# phonegap php does not decoding json

Tags: php, android, json, cordova, rss

i am developing a phonegap application that contain rss reader. i 've make a php page and work successfully on the pc. but when i install the app on my device it doesn't work.
can anyone find a solution or what did i miss. it seems that on the device it does not decoding json. my code is simple you can find it on this link [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GSQSYXv_TQ)

i get this :

```
query->results->item as $post)
{
$title = $post->title;
$link = $post->link;
$desc = $post->description;
$title; 
}
```

on my device screen

Comment: You need to define *how* it isn't working. Have you tried Chrome Remote Debugging?

Comment: Are you actually trying to run the php page in the phone? A phonegap app is not a web server, you can't include php just javascript. If you want to use php, you have to host it on a server.